# docker-compose environment not getting set

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm having a problem with docker-compose : the enviroment part doesn't seem to work anymore on one server whereas the same thing works on other servers.

On the designated server, with this docker-compose :

```
version: '3'
services:
  test:
    image: 'busybox'
    command: env
    environment:
      - HELLO=WORLD
```

Running docker-compose up outputs this :

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=8d4af1fcbe88
HOME=/root
```

No trace of the environment variable `HELLO`

I tried running

```
docker run -e test=plop busybox env
```

It works and outputs

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=5880600fbb99
test=plop
HOME=/root
```

I tried using the latest docker-compose version on github but it changes nothing.

The same problem appears when using `.env` files.

Does anyone has any idea about what could be happening here ?

Edit: To be clear, I already ran this docker-compose on other servers and it works as intended, i was wondering if some people could help me debug this "bug". Here is a walkthrough that explains what I did :

```
/tmp/test$ curl -SsL "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.26.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o docker-compose
/tmp/test$ ls -a
.  ..  docker-compose  docker-compose.yml
/tmp/test$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  test:
    image: 'busybox'
    command: env
    environment:
      - HELLO=WORLD
/tmp/test$ sudo ./docker-compose down
Removing network test_default
WARNING: Network test_default not found.
/tmp/test$ sudo ./docker-compose up -d
Creating network "test_default" with the default driver
Creating test_test_1 ... done
/tmp/test$ sudo docker logs test_test_1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=b68e605e609d
HOME=/root
```

Comment: you have to stop and start again, restarting just reuses the last run config again.

Comment: I had this problem on an entirely different docker-compose. I made sure to change everything (even the directory it was run in) and the problem still happened. I tried doing a docker-compose down before the up

Answer (score 0):

I tried the exact `docker-compose.yml` and I am getting the expected output. Please check the below logs.

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml 
version: '3'
services:
  test:
    image: 'busybox'
    command: env
    environment:
      - HELLO=WORLD

$ docker-compose up
Creating network "cwa-base-webpack_default" with the default driver
Creating test_1 ... done
Attaching to test_1
test_1  | PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
test_1  | HOSTNAME=00bd78e58400
test_1  | HELLO=WORLD
test_1  | HOME=/root
test_1 exited with code 0
```

Few points which you can check:-

- Run `docker-compose down` before you run `docker-compose up` just to rule out any previous deployments.
- Make sure you are using the correct `docker-compose.yml` file i.e. you are in the right directory and using the default file.

Comment: I edited my question with a few more details, but to sum it up, i already tried to run it on others servers and it ran fine on them. I'm trying to understand why it's not working correctly here. This environment problem happens to every docker-compose I tested on this server.

Comment: your server is broken. the software demonstrably works. voting to close

Comment: OK I've seen this github issue https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7423 and it looks like it. IDK how to close though

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the problem was solved by updating docker. 18.09.8 did the trick.
A little weird because docker worked with environment variables.
I guess it was the interaction between the two.
Thank you for helping anyway !